# I need to know how to increase string size in assembly?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

`.rodata:00014844 aFpebfmj1fre5fm DCB "FpebFmJ1FRe5FmTbGRDnGQ==",0`

I have used hex editor to add byte but not work.

Comment: You can't really do that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError why can't do ?

Comment: If something else follows immediately after the variable you wish to expand, that, and everything else after, would have to be relocated, and all references to those locations fixed up.

Answer (score 2):

To increase the size of a string literal, you have to make space for the extra bytes first.

To make space for the extra bytes, you have to move everything that is at a higher address (in all sections).

To move everything that is at a higher address, you can't just move the bytes - you also have to change every instruction that contains an address to the data that was moved.

To change every instruction that contains an address to the data that was moved, you have 2 options:

- Recompile/reassemble/relink the whole thing from its original source code.
- Spend years trying to find and fix every single instruction, then give up when it doesn't work because you missed one somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your target. You asked the right problem, but the question sounds wrong. You don't need to increase size of this string directly. You want to force the code to read another longer string.

Ways to do this:

1. Rebuild code from sources (but I guess your target is proprietary)
2. Change the address of the string in all the code references (sometimes - data references).

The second method requires finding a new address for the string, and you have options:

1. Locate unused string/data in the rodata section. E.g. exception message on program termination (in practice if program crashes you don't need the description of reason - exception if you are author of this program, but in this case you have sources)
2. Locate size alignment at the end of the section/segment. Some compilers leave free space after the all data by default. E.g. your program rodata has a total size of 0x5780, but compiler set segment size to 0x6000 for alignment. In this case, you have 0x6000 - 0x5780 bytes.
3. Append new segement/section to the file. There are a couple of tools and after reading ELF/PE/mach-o description you will be able to make your own.

These things take a lot of time but not years. If you have basic assembly knowledge - like weeks and months to study details.